# Python - Scraping and classifying text in "fonts"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, scrape

I would like to scrape the content of this website https://web.archive.org/web/20130318062052/http://internet.csr.nih.gov/Roster_proto1/member_roster.asp?srg=ACE&SRGDISPLAY=ACE&CID=102283 and create a table with the columns NAME, TITLE, LOCATION. I know some individuals have more or less "lines", but I am just trying to understand how I could even classify the first 3 lines for each person given that the text is in between "fonts" for all.

So far I have:

```
 url="https://web.archive.org/web/20130318062052/http://internet.csr.nih.gov/Roster_proto1/member_roster.asp?srg=ACE&SRGDISPLAY=ACE&CID=102283"
 driver.maximize_window()
 driver.implicitly_wait(5) # wait up to 3 seconds before calls to find elements time out
 driver.get(url)

 content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
 soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")

 column = soup.find_all("font")
```

But once I am there and I have all the text within "font" in my "column" variable, I don't know how to proceed to differentiate between each person and build a loop where I would retrieve name, title, location etc. for each.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: The way that document is structured makes it tough to analyze with BS4. I think you should look for pairs `<br><br>`, as those serve as separators for each record. A custom [function](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#a-function) might help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, would you have any idea about how to look for pairs of <br>, or using something else than BS? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting the text from font tags inside the table or you have not reached there ? The expected text appears to be inside the third table, within fint tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** instead of using selenium, I simply fetched and parsed with `soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")`; as far as I an tell, the required section is not dynamic, so it shouldn't cause any issues.

---

> would you have any idea about how to look for pairs of `<br>`

Since they represent empty lines, you could try simply splitting the text [in that cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxuBl.png) by `\n\n\n`

```py
blockText = soup.select_one('td:has(font)').get_text(' ')
blockText = blockText.replace('-'*10, '\n\n\n') # pad "underlined" lines
blockSections = [sect.strip() for sect in '\n'.join([
    l.strip('-').strip() for l in blockText.splitlines()
]).split('\n\n\n') if sect.strip()]
```

Although, if you looked at [`blockSections`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI8Vv.png), you might notice that some headers [`ROSTER` and `MEMBERS`] get stuck to the end of the previous section - probably because their formatting means that an extra `<br>` is not needed to distinguish them from their adjacent sections. [I added the `.replace('-'*10, '\n\n\n')` line so that at least they're separated from the *next* section.]

Another risk is that I don't know if all versions and parsers will parse `<br><br>` to text as 3 line breaks - some omit `br` space entirely from text, and others might add extra space based on spaces between tags in the source html.

---

It's easier to split if you loop through the `<br>`s and pad them with something more distinctive to split by; the [`.insert...`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert-before-and-insert-after) methods are useful here. (This method also has the advantage of being able to target bolded lined as well.)

```py
blockSoup = soup.select_one('td:has(font)')
for br2 in blockSoup.select('br+br, font:has(br)'): 
    br2.insert_after(BeautifulSoup(f'<p>{"="*80}</p>').p)
    br2.insert_before(BeautifulSoup(f'<p>{"="*80}</p>').p)
blockSections = [
    sect.strip().strip('-').strip() for sect in 
    blockSoup.get_text(' ').split("="*80) if sect.strip()
]
```

This time, `blockSections` looks something like

> ```py
> ['Membership Roster - ACE\n AIDS CLINICAL STUDIES AND EPIDEMIOLOGY STUDY SECTION\n Center For Scientific Review\n (Terms end 6/30 of the designated year)\n ROSTER',
>  'CHAIRPERSON',
>  'SCHACKER, TIMOTHY\n W\n , MD,\n (14)\n PROFESSOR\n DEPARTMENT OF MEDICINE\n UNIVERSITY OF MINNESOTA\n MINNEAPOLIS,\n MN\n 55455',
>  'MEMBERS',
>  'ANDERSON, JEAN\n R\n , MD,\n (14)\n PROFESSOR\n DEPARTMENT OF GYNECOLOGY AND OBSTETRICS\n JOHNS HOPKINS UNIVERSITY\n BALTIMORE,\n MD 21287',
>  'BALASUBRAMANYAM, ASHOK\n , MD,\n (14)\n PROFESSOR\n DEPARTMENT OF MEDICINE AND\n MOLECULAR AND CELLULAR BIOLOGY\n DIVISION OF DIABETES, ENDOCRINOLOGY AND METABOLISM\n BAYLOR COLLEGE OF MEDICINE\n HOUSTON,\n TX 77030',
>  'BLATTNER, WILLIAM\n ALBERT\n , MD,\n (15)\n PROFESSOR AND ASSOCIATE DIRECTOR\n DEPARTMENT OF MEDICNE\n INSTITUTE OF HUMAN VIROLOGY\n UNIVERSITY OF MARYLAND, BALTIMORE\n BALTIMORE,\n MD 21201',
>  'CHEN, YING\n QING\n , PHD,\n (15)\n PROFESSOR\n PROGRAM IN BIOSTATISTICS AND BIOMATHEMATICS\n FRED HUTCHINSON CANCER RESEARCH CENTER\n SEATTLE,\n WA 981091024',
>  'COTTON, DEBORAH\n , MD,\n (13)\n PROFESSOR\n SECTION OF INFECTIOUS DISEASES\n DEPARTMENT OF MEDICINE\n BOSTON UNIVERSITY\n BOSTON,\n MA 02118',
>  'DANIELS, MICHAEL\n J\n , SCD,\n (16)\n PROFESSOR\n DEPARTMENT OF BIOSTATISTICS\n UNIVERSITY OF TEXAS AT AUSTIN\n AUSTIN,\n TX 78712',
>  'FOULKES, ANDREA\n SARAH\n , SCD,\n (14)\n ASSOCIATE PROFESSOR\n DEPARTMENT OF BIOSTATISTICS\n UNIVERSITY OF MASSACHUSETTS\n AMHERST,\n MA 01003',
>  'HEROLD, BETSY\n C\n , MD,\n (16)\n PROFESSOR\n DEPARTMENT OF PEDIATRICS\n ALBERT EINSTEIN COLLEGE OF MEDICINE\n BRONX,\n NY 10461',
>  'JUSTICE, AMY\n CAROLINE\n , MD, PHD,\n (16)\n PROFESSOR\n DEPARTMENT OF PEDIATRICS\n YALE UNIVERSITY\n NEW HAVEN,\n CT 06520',
>  'KATZENSTEIN, DAVID\n ALLENBERG\n , MD,\n (13)\n PROFESSOR\n DIVISION OF INFECTIOUS DISEASES\n STANFORD UNIVERSITY SCHOOL OF MEDICINE\n STANFORD,\n CA 94305',
>  'MARGOLIS, DAVID\n M\n , MD,\n (14)\n PROFESSOR\n DEPARTMENT OF MEDICINE\n UNIVERSITY OF NORTH CAROLINA, CHAPEL HILL\n CHAPEL HILL,\n NC 27599',
>  'MONTANER, LUIS\n J\n , DVM, PHD,\n (13)\n PROFESSOR\n DEPARTMENT OF IMMUNOLOGY\n THE WISTAR INSTITUTE\n PHILADELPHIA,\n PA 19104',
>  'MONTANO, MONTY\n A\n , PHD,\n (15)\n RESEARCH SCIENTIST\n DEPARTMENT OF IMMUNOLOGY AND\n INFECTIOUS DISEASES\n BOSTON UNIVERSITY\n BOSTON,\n MA 02115',
>  'PAGE, KIMBERLY\n , PHD, MPH,\n (16)\n PROFESSOR\n DIVISION OF PREVENTIVE MEDICINE AND PUBLIC HEALTH\n AND GLOBAL HEALTH SCIENCES\n DEPARTMENT OF EPIDEMIOLOGY AND BIOSTATICTICS\n UNIVERSITY OF CALIFORNIA, SAN FRANCISCO\n UNIVERSITY OF CALIFORNIA, SAN FRANCISCO\n SAN FRANCISCO,\n CA 94105',
>  'SHIKUMA, CECILIA\n M\n , MD,\n (15)\n PROFESSOR\n DEPARTMENT OF MEDICINE\n HAWAII AIDS CLINICAL RESEARCH PROGRAM\n UNIVERSITY OF HAWAII\n HONOLULU,\n HI 96816',
>  'WOOD, CHARLES\n , PHD,\n (13)\n PROFESSOR\n UNIVERSITY OF NEBRASKA\n LINCOLN,\n NE 68588']
> ```

---

> create a table with the columns NAME, TITLE, LOCATION

There may be a more elegant solution, but I feel like the simplest way would be to just loop the siblings of the headers and keep count of consecutive `br`s.

```py
doubleBr = soup.select('br')[:2] # [ so the last person also gets added ]
personsList = []
for f in soup.select('td>font>font:has(b br)'):
    role, lCur,pCur,brCt = f.get_text(' ').strip('-').strip(), [],[],0 
    for lf in f.find_next_siblings(['font','br'])+doubleBr:
        brCt = brCt+1 if lf.name == 'br' else 0 
        if pCur and (brCt>1 or lf.b):
            pDets = {'role': role, 'name': '?'} # initiate

            if len(pCur)>1: pDets['title'] = pCur[1]
            pDets['name'], pCur = pCur[0], pCur[2:]
            
            dList = pCur[:-2] 
            pDets['departments'] = dList[0] if len(dList)==1 else dList

            if len(pCur)>1: pDets['institute'] = pCur[-2]
            if pCur: pDets['location'] = pCur[-1]

            personsList.append(pDets)      
            pCur, lCur, brCt = [], [], 0 # clear
        if lf.b: break # rached next section
        if lf.name == 'font': # [split and join to minimize whitespace]
            lCur.append(' '.join(lf.get_text(' ').split())) # add to line
        if brCt and lCur: pCur, lCur = pCur+[' '.join(lCur)], [] # newline
```

Since [`personsList`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyZ9B.png) is a list of dictionaries, it can be tabulated as simply as  `pandas.DataFrame(personsList)` to get a DataFrame that looks like:

| role | name | title | departments | institute | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CHAIRPERSON | SCHACKER, TIMOTHY W , MD | PROFESSOR | DEPARTMENT OF MEDICINE | UNIVERSITY OF MINNESOTA | MINNEAPOLIS, MN 55455 |
| MEMBERS | ANDERSON, JEAN R , MD | PROFESSOR | DEPARTMENT OF GYNECOLOGY AND OBSTETRICS | JOHNS HOPKINS UNIVERSITY | BALTIMORE, MD 21287 |
| MEMBERS | BALASUBRAMANYAM, ASHOK , MD | PROFESSOR | ['DEPARTMENT OF MEDICINE AND', 'MOLECULAR AND CELLULAR BIOLOGY', 'DIVISION OF DIABETES, ENDOCRINOLOGY AND METABOLISM'] | BAYLOR COLLEGE OF MEDICINE | HOUSTON, TX 77030 |
| MEMBERS | BLATTNER, WILLIAM ALBERT , MD | PROFESSOR AND ASSOCIATE DIRECTOR | ['DEPARTMENT OF MEDICNE', 'INSTITUTE OF HUMAN VIROLOGY'] | UNIVERSITY OF MARYLAND, BALTIMORE | BALTIMORE, MD 21201 |
| MEMBERS | CHEN, YING QING , PHD | PROFESSOR | PROGRAM IN BIOSTATISTICS AND BIOMATHEMATICS | FRED HUTCHINSON CANCER RESEARCH CENTER | SEATTLE, WA 981091024 |
| MEMBERS | COTTON, DEBORAH , MD | PROFESSOR | ['SECTION OF INFECTIOUS DISEASES', 'DEPARTMENT OF MEDICINE'] | BOSTON UNIVERSITY | BOSTON, MA 02118 |
| MEMBERS | DANIELS, MICHAEL J , SCD | PROFESSOR | DEPARTMENT OF BIOSTATISTICS | UNIVERSITY OF TEXAS AT AUSTIN | AUSTIN, TX 78712 |
| MEMBERS | FOULKES, ANDREA SARAH , SCD | ASSOCIATE PROFESSOR | DEPARTMENT OF BIOSTATISTICS | UNIVERSITY OF MASSACHUSETTS | AMHERST, MA 01003 |
| MEMBERS | HEROLD, BETSY C , MD | PROFESSOR | DEPARTMENT OF PEDIATRICS | ALBERT EINSTEIN COLLEGE OF MEDICINE | BRONX, NY 10461 |
| MEMBERS | JUSTICE, AMY CAROLINE , MD, PHD | PROFESSOR | DEPARTMENT OF PEDIATRICS | YALE UNIVERSITY | NEW HAVEN, CT 06520 |
| MEMBERS | KATZENSTEIN, DAVID ALLENBERG , MD | PROFESSOR | DIVISION OF INFECTIOUS DISEASES | STANFORD UNIVERSITY SCHOOL OF MEDICINE | STANFORD, CA 94305 |
| MEMBERS | MARGOLIS, DAVID M , MD | PROFESSOR | DEPARTMENT OF MEDICINE | UNIVERSITY OF NORTH CAROLINA, CHAPEL HILL | CHAPEL HILL, NC 27599 |
| MEMBERS | MONTANER, LUIS J , DVM, PHD | PROFESSOR | DEPARTMENT OF IMMUNOLOGY | THE WISTAR INSTITUTE | PHILADELPHIA, PA 19104 |
| MEMBERS | MONTANO, MONTY A , PHD | RESEARCH SCIENTIST | ['DEPARTMENT OF IMMUNOLOGY AND', 'INFECTIOUS DISEASES'] | BOSTON UNIVERSITY | BOSTON, MA 02115 |
| MEMBERS | PAGE, KIMBERLY , PHD, MPH | PROFESSOR | ['DIVISION OF PREVENTIVE MEDICINE AND PUBLIC HEALTH', 'AND GLOBAL HEALTH SCIENCES', 'DEPARTMENT OF EPIDEMIOLOGY AND BIOSTATICTICS', 'UNIVERSITY OF CALIFORNIA, SAN FRANCISCO'] | UNIVERSITY OF CALIFORNIA, SAN FRANCISCO | SAN FRANCISCO, CA 94105 |
| MEMBERS | SHIKUMA, CECILIA M , MD | PROFESSOR | ['DEPARTMENT OF MEDICINE', 'HAWAII AIDS CLINICAL RESEARCH PROGRAM'] | UNIVERSITY OF HAWAII | HONOLULU, HI 96816 |
| MEMBERS | WOOD, CHARLES , PHD | PROFESSOR | [] | UNIVERSITY OF NEBRASKA | LINCOLN, NE 68588 |

---

[ Btw, if the *`.select('br+br, font:has(br)')`* and *`.select('td>font>font:has(b br)')`* parts are unfamiliar to you, you can look up [`.select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php). [Combinators](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/combinators/) [like `>`/`+`/`,`]  and [pseudo-classes](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/pseudo-classes/) [like `:has`] allow us to get very specific with out targets. ]